# How to understand logical implication in Set theory?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading about the wiki page of [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (a.k.a logical implication).

In the diagram in that page (which is also pasted here), it draws an Venne Diagram of the truth function of $ A \implies B $

[image]

In the text explanation (in 2nd paragraph), it says $\ P \implies Q $ can be symbolized using set theory:
$ P \supset Q $

Question: The Diagram explanation and text explanation is conflicting. It seems in the diagram, A is not a superset of B. What is the correct way to understand it?

Comment: Honestly, you don't appear to have read the caption of the image that you took from the linked wikipedia article. It explains that the white area is the set of items for which the material implication is false. Also it doesn't say that it can be symbolized using set theory, it says that the symbol can be used for implication, but also has a meaning in set theory.

Comment: With the "horseshoe" symbol: $\supset$ he does not mean "superset". It is the symbol used sometimes (mainly: beginning XX Century) in place of $\to$ of $\Rightarrow$. See [The Notation in *Principia Mathematica*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/#PrimSymb).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that $$A \to B \equiv \neg(A \wedge \neg B)$$

Note that $A \wedge \neg B$ represents the portion of the set A excluding the area of intersection of $A$ and $B$ (the *white portion*). The negation gives us the required red area.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Omega$ a set, from which we get arguments for the predicates $P(\cdot), Q(\cdot)$. Let $x\in \Omega$ such that the implication $P(x)\implies Q(x)$. This implication is true, only when $Q(x)$ is true *or* $P(x)$ is false. Thus collecting the points of $\Omega$, for which the implication stands, we have

$\{x\in \Omega | P(x)\implies Q(x)\}=\{x\in \Omega| Q(x) \vee (\sim P(x)) \}=\{x\in \Omega|Q(x)\}\cup \{x\in \Omega | \sim P(x)\}=\{x\in \Omega|Q(x)\}\cup (\Omega \setminus \{x\in \Omega | P(x)\}).~ (1)$

The set $\{x\in \Omega|Q(x)\}$ can be seen as the set $ \{x\in \Omega | P(x)\}$ in above figure and the second as the left, so the red is described from the expression $(1)$.